# What happened to the rep levels for public-beta? One day I had mod tools, the next day they're gone?

Tags: support, moderators, beta, privileges

And oddly enough, I still have mods tools on meta?

Comment: That is odd.  The FAQ on Android.SE and the Meta have different rep levels required.  It looks like they upped the mod tools level on the main site to 10,000.

Comment: They both used to be the lower amounts.  It jumped up a few days ago.

Comment: Any mods out there to shed some light?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Perhaps we made an error:

[Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)